# Increment numbers in a string

Tags: scripts

I've been looking for a way to increment numbers in a long string of mine :

```
run("Bio-Formats", "open=/Users/m-a/Desktop/test_stabilite001.nd2 color_mode=Default rois_import=[ROI manager] split_channels view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT series_1");
run("Bio-Formats", "open=/Users/m-a/Desktop/test_stabilite002.nd2 color_mode=Default rois_import=[ROI manager] split_channels view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT series_1");
run("Bio-Formats", "open=/Users/m-a/Desktop/test_stabilite003.nd2 color_mode=Default rois_import=[ROI manager] split_channels view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT series_1");
run("Bio-Formats", "open=/Users/m-a/Desktop/test_stabilite004.nd2 color_mode=Default rois_import=[ROI manager] split_channels view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT series_1");
run("Concatenate...", "  title=TL open image1=[test_stabilite001.nd2 - test_stabilite001.nd2 (series 01) - C=0] image2=[test_stabilite002.nd2 - test_stabilite002.nd2 (series 01) - C=0] image3=[test_stabilite003.nd2 - test_stabilite003.nd2 (series 01) - C=0] image4=[test_stabilite004.nd2 - test_stabilite004.nd2 (series 01) - C=0] image5=[-- None --]");
run("Concatenate...", "  title=GFP open image1=[test_stabilite001.nd2 - test_stabilite001.nd2 (series 01) - C=1] image2=[test_stabilite002.nd2 - test_stabilite002.nd2 (series 01) - C=1] image3=[test_stabilite003.nd2 - test_stabilite003.nd2 (series 01) - C=1] image4=[test_stabilite004.nd2 - test_stabilite004.nd2 (series 01) - C=1] image5=[-- None --]");
selectWindow("TL");
saveAs("Tiff", "/Users/m-a/Desktop/Test/Test_Serie1_TL.tif");
selectWindow("GFP");
saveAs("Tiff", "/Users/m-a/Desktop/Test/Test_Serie1_GFP.tif");
selectWindow("Test_Serie1_TL.tif");
close();
selectWindow("Test_Serie1_GFP.tif");
close();
```

For time saving purposes I want to find an easy way to replace "series_1", "series 01" and "Serie1" by "series_n+1", "series 0n+1" and "Serien+1" approximately 50 times.
I've been looking around for a while but could not find anything to help me with this.

Help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: So what's the rule for the replacements ? Replace underscore between "series" and a digit string ? What about the 01 part ? Are you expecting numbers to be larger than 99 ?

Comment: Read `man seq`.

Comment: What language is this "script" written in? What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this within vim using the following command:

```
g/[Ss]erie\(s[ _]\|\)\d*/ normal gn^An^An^An^A
```

To use it, open your text example in vim, then press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then <kbd>:</kbd>, then the above line. However, whenever `^A` needs to be typed, type <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, which will insert a literal `^A` symbol. It should just show up as `^A`.

This will find all the patterns in your example and increment the number in it by one. Here is how it works:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> will enter command mode in vim.
- the command executed is the `g` command. It will run a command on all lines matching some regular expression.
- `[Ss]erie\(s[ _]\|\)\d*` is the regular expression that should match all the patterns you requested. That is `serie` starting with capital or not capital `s`, followed by `s` and a space or `_`, or followed by nothing. Then followed by a number.
- the command executed on every line by the `g` command will actually be 8 commands:

  - `normal` is just a keyword telling vim that what follows are not command line mode commands, but *normal* mode commands. That is, things you would normally just type when normally editing in vim.
  - `gn` moves the cursor to the place where the last match was found
  - <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> increments the number (this would also work when you move the cursor to that position manually and just press it).
  - `n` moves to the next match. This is repeated 3 times.

This will need vim 7.4 and upwards to work. Also it will need adjustment if you have more than 4 occurrences of the pattern in a line.

I should note that using scripts or editor magic to change program code like this is quite a silly way to work. It would be much better to improve your program to generate the strings programmatically in an appropriate way.

Note: Your code looks like [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/). If that is the case, here is a document that could help you achieve something a little bit better: http://www.sussex.ac.uk/gdsc/intranet/pdfs/ImageJBatchProcessing.pdf

Comment: Answer box is too short let me put a proper answer ;)

Comment: @J.Des You can always use pastebin or paste.ubuntu.com and provide links to long code or termimal output. Posting comments as answers isn't acceptable

Comment: ok, shame on me. This doesn't work as I expected (although in my tests it seemed so). I will try to find a way. In the mean time you probably should have a look at fixing your ImageJ macro and use the builtin mechanisms for iterating.

Comment: I'm taking a look at it and trying to see how to get the macro to run through series, thanks for the help

Comment: I've find a way around this using : "g/serie\(s[ ]\)\d*/ normal gn^An^An^An^A ^@ g/[Ss]erie\(s[_]\|\)\d*/ normal gn^A" Now I want to copy a line, increment it and then paste the line (if I had a line with a value of 1 it would now be 2 and I would have pasted a line with the value 1 in front) but when I try to do that it won't paste anything... the command I use is ":v/[1,14]y[ank] ["+] ^@ g/serie\(s[ ]\)\d*/ normal gn^An^An^An^A ^@ g/[Ss]erie\(s[_]\|\)\d*/ normal gn^A ^@ v/[1]pu[t] ["+]  "